# Launching JAR executables with self healing?

Tags: command-line, server, python, java, crash

I am running an Android app server using Ubuntu 20.04 and wanted to know how to make sure my server app is back up again after it has crashed?
The app is created in Kotlin and the result is a .jar file.
I know that I can run a command -java -jar myfile.jar in command prompt once.
But if randomly the program crashes then automatically the .jar should be launched again.
How to do this in a memory/disk/CPU efficient way?